# How to dump SQL Server data into csv

Tags: sql-server, database, conventions

I'm converting web application written in ASP into PHP that will be using MySQL. I have a SQL Server database with two files (`.MDF` and `.LDF`) I want to convert into CSV file but I am having trouble finding the right tool to do the job. I found that some people are suggesting SQL Server Express. I tried it but couldn't figure out how to load database from file and use it. I also tried to use opendbcopy but when trying to open a file it doesn't show it in the file pane.

Comment: If you have SQL Server installed (Express with Tools, or a full version), you'll have SQL Server **Integration Services** (SSIS) which easily allows you to dump your SQL Server data into any format you like.

Comment: [This article here shows an alternative way](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2011/01/sql-server-export-table-to-csv.html) of exporting your data to CSV using the `bcp` command-line tool. But again: first you need to have SQL Server installed and the database attached to it... (you cannot just access the `.mdf/.ldf` files "on the fly")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install SQL Server Express, you can load the image file using the Attach Database functionality in the SQL Server Management Studio (the management UI).

Then you can view and work with the database directly from Management Studio, where you can export the file to CSV by right-clicking the database name and selecting Tasks->Export Data.

Comment: Roy thanks, your answer helped me a lot. I will add that I had to run SQL Server Management as Administrator otherwise I was getting an error when trying to open mdf file.

Answer (score 2):

There's an online service called RebaseData that can do the job. You just need to upload your `.MDF` file and it gets converted to a `.ZIP` archive. The `.ZIP` archive will contain several `.CSV` files, one for each table of the database.

[Link to the converter](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-mdf-to-csv-online)

Disclaimer: I'm working for that service.

Answer (score 1):

connect database to visual studio and write query to display all data from the table you want and then right click and select all and again right click and save it .
Its done !